# TypeORM Migrations run, can't seed (no connections?! in migration)

Tags: node.js, migration, entity, typeorm

I am working on my first TypeScript project, which is based off of this template:
https://github.com/ljlm0402/typescript-express-starter

I am working on adding migrations to our app, up to this point we have been relying on the automigration functionality and dropping / recreating DB/Tables as entities are updated. We would like to add a "default user" to our system via the migrations... but because of the way the app is running the up/down functions in the migration for some reason CAN create/drop tables but CAN NOT access any of these tables to insert data into them (??!!).

I am worried it may be a .env / ormconfig.js issue, and also the layer of how TS is compiled to JS makes me worry that for some reason my app is not reading the right config file.

How to reproduce this:

`ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config ./ormconfig.js "migration:run"`

ormconfig.js:

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

module.exports = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.POSTGRESQL_HOST,
  port: process.env.POSTGRESQL_PORT,
  username: process.env.POSTGRESQL_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.POSTGRESQL_DATABASE,
  synchronize: true,
  logging: false,
  entities: [env === 'production' ? 'build/entity/*{.ts,.js}' : 'src/entity/*{.ts,.js}'],
  migrations: [env === 'production' ? 'build/migration/*{.ts,.js}' : 'src/migration/*{.ts,.js}'],
  subscribers: [env === 'production' ? 'build/subscriber/*{.ts,.js}' : 'src/subscriber/*{.ts,.js}'],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: 'src/entity',
    migrationsDir: 'src/migration',
    subscribersDir: 'src/subscriber',
  },
};
```

Migration (trimmed for brevity)

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner, TableColumn } from 'typeorm';
import userService from '../services/user.service';

export class SeedDefaultUser1610084649009 implements MigrationInterface {
  
  public userService = new userService();

  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {

    const dbs = await queryRunner.getDatabases(); // returns empty array []
    const schemas = await queryRunner.getSchemas(); // returns empty array []
    console.log(dbs, schemas);

    await queryRunner.createTable(
      new Table({
        name: 'user_entity',
        columns: [
          {
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int',
            isPrimary: true,
          },
          {
            name: 'email',
            type: 'varchar',
          },
        ],
      }),
      true,
    ); // Despite no db connections, this works! tables exist!   

    const user: User = await this.userService.create(
      {
        email: 'admin@email.com',
      },
    ); // This fails with:
       //QueryFailedError: relation "user_entity" does not exist

  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert fake data using TypeOrm, you need to create seeds instead of migrations.

Migrations are used to create tables, seeds are used to fill them with data.

You can follow this [medium article](https://medium.com/the-crowdlinker-chronicle/seeding-databases-using-nestjs-cd6634e8efc5) to create a seed, [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-seeding) or [faker.js](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/)